# How can I implement right swipe off functionality in a material-UI Snackbar component?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a hybrid mobile app, where I am using Material-ui Snackbar component in my Cordova react based project.I want to implement a swipe off functionality ,so that the Snackbar can be dismissed with swipe right action.Currently it works with onClick event.I could not find anything in the material-ui Snackbar documentation

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit the question accordingly. You need to show us what you have already have/tried in order to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution to this question too. To solve this you will have to implement this functionality yourself.

1. Detect the touch events, add onTouchStart, onTouchEnd, onTouchMove in the Material-UI Snackbar.
2. Look for the x position of the touch drag in the events. The drag position of the touch on the screen has to be detected on touch start and end. Create a new state with the drag start position onTouchStart.
3. Set the state of the drag start position in the functions that handles onTouchStart.
4. Then in onTouchEnd compare the drag start position with the drag end position. If it has changed over a certain threshold then trigger the closing event of the Snackbar.
5. To make the Snackbar draggable over the screen use onTouchMove, another position x state and a marginLeft to move the Snackbar. Use onTouchMove to set the state of the positionX to the onTouchMove x position minus onTouchStart x position. Use positionX as the left margin for the snackbar to move it. Don't forget to reset the positionX after the Snackbar is dismissed, otherwise it will display at the position of the last time the Snackbar was swiped left or right.

Here is the result:

```
const SnackbarComponent = ({ open, onClose }) => {

  const [dragX, setDragX] = useState(null)
  const [positionX, setPositionX] = useState(0)

  const handleTouchStart = event => {
    const startDragX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX
    setDragX(startDragX)
  }

  const handleTouchEnd = event => {
    const endDragX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX
    if (Math.abs(dragX - endDragX) > 50) {
      onClose(event)
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPositionX(0)
    }, 500)
  }

  const handleTouchMove = event => {
    const positionX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX
    setPositionX(positionX - dragX)
  }

  return (
    <Snackbar
      message={'Snackbar message'}
      style={{ marginLeft: positionX }}
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
      onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
      onTouchStart={handleTouchStart}
      onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
    />
  )
}
```

This will only work on Touch devices, to enable it for mouse events too use the onDragStart, onDragStop, and onDrag and add the draggable={true} prop to the component. Use event.clientX to get the x position of the cursor.